# xcode 4 user interface item identifier

Tags: xcode4

What is the new "User Interface Item Identifier" used for? I cannot seem to find any documentation on it.

I know the old "Label" was for IB use only. Is the new field the same thing?

[image]

Comment: maybe its tag. do you have "tag" field?

Comment: yeah there is still a tag field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a [new protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSUserInterfaceItemIdentification_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html). Turns out, NSCell and NSView [conform](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/MacOSXLionAPIDiffs/AppKit.html) to the protocol. If I set the value in Xcode, then call

```
NSLog(@"ident: %@", [myField identifier]);
```

it logs the string as expected. Yay! You must make the Base SDK in the build settings 10.7 though.

Answer (score 1):

It's used as part of the Cocoa Autolayout feature, introduced in Lion.